# why when I create a new class in a new package in Swarm it does not work?

Tags: swarm, wildfly-swarm

I use Swarm 2017.3.X and 2017.5.0. When I add a new class in a new package I get NoClassDefFoundError caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on runtime. Why?

```
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/myapp/newpackage/NewClass
at com.example.myapp.MyBean.getSomething(MyBean.java:51)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:139)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:236)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:402)
... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.myapp.newpackage.NewClass from [Module "deployment.198f19d8-46c4-4bf5-96fd-101dc0f57abd.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
... 57 more
```

Swarm finds all the Java classes in *com.example.myapp* (where Main.java is) but not the classes in *com.example.myapp.newpackage* (where NewClass.java is).

Answer (score 0):

In Swarm you have to add each package in Main class:

```
    deployment.addPackage(Main.class.getPackage());
    deployment.addPackage(NewClass.class.getPackage()); //new
    deployment.addAllDependencies();
```

Then it works!

Comment: Note that in the vast majority of cases, you don't really have to use a custom main method and manually construct a deployment. If you're using the main method for configuring Swarm, then `project-defaults.yml` is probably a better choice, and even if you really need to use custom main method, you don't always have to construct the deployment manually, as the default deployment will probably be exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into that.